# Creating P/L Column in Pandas from and Open and Close Price based on whether is a long or short position

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, finance

This one has been bothering me for awhile.  I have all the pieces (I think) that work individually to create the output I'm looking for (calculate a profit and loss for a stock), but when put together they return nothing.

The dataframe itself is pretty self-explanatory so I haven't included an example.  Basically the series includes Stock Symbol, Opening Time, Opening Price, Closing Time, Closing Price, and whether or not it was a long or short position.

Here's my code to calculate the P-L for a long position:

```
import pandas as pd
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import time

def create_df3():
    return pd.read_excel('Base_Sheet.xlsx', sheet_name="Closed_Pos", header=0)

def update_price(sym):
    return si.get_live_price(sym)

long_pl_calc = ((df3['Close_Price']) / (df3['Entry_Price'])) - 1

close_long_pl = df3['P-L'].isnull and (df3['Long_Short'] == 'Long')

for row in df3.iterrows():
     if close_long_pl is True:
         return df3['P-L'].apply(long_pl_calc)
```

If I print long_pl_calc or close_long_pl, I get exactly what I expect.  However, when I iterate through the series to return the calculation, I still end up with a 'NaN' value (but not an error).

Any help would be appreciated!  I already know the solution I came to is terrible, but I've also tried at least a dozen other iterations with no success either.

Comment: Here's another attempt I made today:

Comment: I tried another strategy today that didn't work either (provided a calculation for both Long and Short positions):  'ls_col = df3['Long_Short']
    long_cond = ls_col == 'Long'
    for row in long_cond:
        df3['P-L'] = df3['P-L'].fillna((df3['Close_Price'])/(df3['Entry_Price'])-1)'

Answer (score 0):

Create a column `df3['Long']` with 1 for the date you are long and 0 for the rest, then to have your long P&L (you could do the same for the short but don't forget to take the opposite sign of the daily return) you can do :

```
df['P&L Long'] = ((df3['Close_Price'] / df3['Entry_Price']) - 1) * df['Long']
```

Then for your `df3['P-L']` it will be:

```
df['P-L'] = df['P&L Long'] + df['P&L Short']
```